# Break up rows representing long time intervals into multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe (tibble) with multiple rows, each row contains an IDNR, a start date, an end date and an exposure status. The IDNR is a character variable, the start and end date are date variables and the exposure status is a numerical variable. This is what the top 3 rows look like:

```
# A tibble: 48,266 x 4

   IDNR                 start      end        exposure
   <chr>                <date>     <date>        <dbl>
 1 1                    2018-02-15 2018-07-01        0
 2 2                    2017-10-30 2018-07-01        0
 3 3                    2016-02-11 2016-12-03        1

# ... with 48,256 more rows
```

In order to do a time-varying cox regression, I want to split up the rows into 90 day parts, while maintaining the start and end date. Here is an example of what I would like to achieve. What happens, is that the new end date is start + 90 days, and a new row is created. This row has the start date which is the same as the end date from the previous row. If the time between start and end is now less than 90 days, this is fine (as for IDNR 1 and 3), however, for IDNR 2 the time is still exceeding 90 days. Therefore a third row needs to be added.

```
# A tibble: 48,266 x 4
# Groups:   IDNR [33,240]
   IDNR                 start      end        exposure
   <chr>                <date>     <date>        <dbl>
 1 1                    2018-02-15 2018-05-16        0
 2 1                    2018-05-16 2018-07-01        0
 3 2                    2017-10-30 2018-01-28        0
 4 2                    2018-01-28 2018-04-28        0
 5 2                    2018-04-28 2018-07-01        0
 6 3                    2016-02-11 2016-08-09        1
 7 3                    2016-08-09 2016-12-03        1
```

I'm relatively new to coding in R, but I've found dplyr to be very useful so far. So, if someone knows a solution using dplyr I would really appreciate that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you elaborate the logic more? You only provide three rows and I just can't straight away see the logic.

Comment: In a later stage of the analysis, I will use this dataframe for a time-varying cox regression. Since I want to update covariates for each person (= each IDNR) at 90 day intervals, I will use this dataframe as a 'backbone' to fill in the covariates. So for example the presence of an allergic reaction in a person might have changed in the 90 days, and that can then be coded as a 0 or 1 at each time interval. I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Or maybe I interpreted your question wrong and is this the answer you are looking for. In the dataset I try to create, the time between start and end is never more than 90 days. If the time is more than 90 days, the end date has to be set to start + 90 days and a new row needs to be added that contains the end-date from the previous one. This new row will have a start date which is the same as the end date from the previous row. If the time between the new start date and the end date is then no longer than 90 days, it is fine. Otherwise, another row needs to be added (this happens in IDNR 2).

Comment: Perfectly clear question, very well done indeed for a first contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

Using `df` as your data frame:

```
df = data.frame(IDNR = 1:3, 
                start = c("2018-02-15","2017-10-30","2016-02-11"),
                end = c("2018-07-01","2018-07-01","2016-12-03"),
                exposure = c(0,0,1))
```

Do:

```
library(lubridate)    

newDF = apply(df, 1, function(x){
    newStart = seq(from = ymd(x["start"]), to = ymd(x["end"]), by = 90)
    newEnd = c(seq(from = ymd(x["start"]), to = ymd(x["end"]), by = 90)[-1], ymd(x["end"]))
    d = data.frame(IDNR = rep(x["IDNR"], length(newStart)), 
                   start = newStart, 
                   end = newEnd, 
                   exposure = rep(x["exposure"], length(newStart)))
})

newDF = do.call(rbind, newDF)

newDF = newDF[newDF$start != newDF$end,]
```

Result:

```
> newDF
  IDNR      start        end exposure
1    1 2018-02-15 2018-05-16        0
2    1 2018-05-16 2018-07-01        0
3    2 2017-10-30 2018-01-28        0
4    2 2018-01-28 2018-04-28        0
5    2 2018-04-28 2018-07-01        0
6    3 2016-02-11 2016-05-11        1
7    3 2016-05-11 2016-08-09        1
8    3 2016-08-09 2016-11-07        1
9    3 2016-11-07 2016-12-03        1
```

What this does is create a sequence of days from `start` to `end` by 90 days and create a smaller data frame with them along with the `IDNR` and `exposure`. This apply will return a list of data frames that you can join together using `do.call`.  The last line removes lines that have the same `start` and `end` date